# Integração NodeJS com DLL

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, dll

Estou precisando fazer NodeJS ler uma DLL para criar uma API Rest.

Tenho o arquivo .dll, mas não tenho o código fonte, essa .dll está em um programa em C# chinês. 
O que quero, é utilizar essa .dll criando uma API rest com Nodejs, e fazer o front-end em Reactjs.

É possível fazer?
Tem alguém que já tenha feito?

Já li um pouco por aí, mas os artigos que encontrei mencionaram alterações nos arquivos .dll para o nodejs conseguir chamar, mas como mencionei, não tenho o código fonte.

Obrigado desde já.
Estou á disposição para esclarecer mais detalhes se for necessário.

Comment: Sugiro que estude a biblioteca `Edge` do `NodeJS`.

Comment: Obrigado Igor, vou estudar essa lib.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma lib chamada Edge. Na sua documentação ela orienta como executar uma função de uma DLL.

```js
var hello = require('edge').func({
    assemblyFile: 'My.Edge.Samples.dll',
    typeName: 'Samples.FooBar.MyType',
    methodName: 'MyMethod' // Func<object,Task<object>>
}});

hello('Node.js', function (error, result) { ... });
```

Segue a página da biblioteca: [Edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge)

Comment: Obrigado Fredson.
Sabe me adiantar se é preciso fazer alguma alteração na DLL pra conseguir obter resultado?

Comment: Não. segundo a documentação, apenas é preciso que você saiba qual o nome do método você deve chamar.

Comment: Show... vou estudar ela aqui. muito obrigado. Qualquer coisa postarei o resultado aqui de conclusão